# qmake to cmake conversion and link errors

Tags: c++, qt, linker, cmake, qmake

I converted a project from qmake (Initially I used qt-creator to build it on mac/linux/win) to cmake and I get a lot of link errors.

For example:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "runion(QtRegion const&, QtRegion const&)", referenced from:
      Q3DView::ReloadLineData() in 3DView.cpp.o
  "pafrand(int)", referenced from:

My .pro file:

```
CONFIG += debug_and_release
QT            += core gui opengl
DEFINES       += _TEST1
TEMPLATE      = app
TARGET        = test
HEADERS       = xxx.h \
                xxxxxx.h \
                etc.h
    Libs/include/generic/xxxxxx.h

SOURCES       = xxxx.cpp \
                xxx.cpp \
                xxxx.cpp 

INCLUDEPATH   += Libs/include
INCLUDEPATH   += ../plugin/srv

RESOURCES     = resource.qrc

##### LINUX
unix:!macx:INCLUDEPATH += . /usr/local/include/boost  
unix:!macx:LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib
unix:!macx:LIBS += -lboost_system -lboost_thread
!win32:!macx: LIBS = -lGL -lGLU
########

#### MAC
macx:INCLUDEPATH += . /usr/local/include/boost
macx:LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib
macx:LIBS += -lboost_system-mt -lboost_thread-mt
macx:QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH += /usr/local/lib
####

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON =

FORMS += \
    UI/xxx.ui \
    UI/xx.ui
```

And my version of the cmake file:

```
project( test )

cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.6 )

if(APPLE)
set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES x86_64)
ENDIF()

set ( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug )

add_definitions ( -Wall )

find_package ( Qt4 REQUIRED )

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost)
IF (Boost_FOUND)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    ADD_DEFINITIONS( "-DHAS_BOOST" )
ENDIF()

find_package(GLUT)
find_package(OpenGL)
IF(APPLE)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "-framework OpenGL -framework GLUT")
ENDIF(APPLE)

set ( test_HDRS
    xxxx.h
    xxxxxx.h
    xxxx.h
    )

set ( test_SRCS
    xxxxx.cpp
    xxx.cpp
    xxxxx.cpp
    )

set ( test_UIS
    UI/xx.ui
    UI/xxxx.ui
    )
QT4_WRAP_UI(UIS ${test_UIS})

set ( test_RSCS
    resource.qrc
    )

QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(RSCS ${test_RSCS})

QT4_WRAP_CPP(MOCS ${test_HDRS})

INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${QT_DEFINITIONS})

include_directories (
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    ${QT_QTCORE_INCLUDE_DIR} ${QT_QTGUI_INCLUDE_DIR} ${QT_QTCORE_INCLUDE_DIR} ${QT_QTGUI_INCLUDE_DIR} ${QT_QTOPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}
    Libs/include
    /usr/local/include/boost
    ../plugin/srv)

link_directories (
        /usr/local/lib
    )

add_executable ( test ${test_SRCS} ${UIS} ${RSCS} ${TRS} ${MOCS} )

target_link_libraries ( test  ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY} ${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY} ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY} ${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY} ${QT_QTOPENGL_LIBRARY} )
```

I tried many different things I found online but always the same problem.
Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: linking with QGIS is not needed. the "LINUX" section of my qmake file isnt correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't linking `-lqgis_core -lqgis_gui` in your `CMakeLists.txt`. Add `qgis_core` and `qgis_gui` into `target_link_libraries()` call.

Comment: My bad!! the qgis is not needed there. But the problem is that even with my source file, it can link. As you can see the error is about my our source, not the external libs.

Comment: You aren't linking Boost libs too, by the way. Maybe it's the cause of error?

Comment: I have no idea what "reunion()" is. About the boost, does the "find boost" bit handles the link too? How to I add it? Boost as you say its a problem too but Im getting a lot of errors even before going into files that need boost. Linking with internal functions give error even before boost.

Comment: find boost (or find any other package) will not automatically add libraries to your target_link_libraries. You need to do that yourself.